# SVG - circle stretched in responsive lines

Tags: html, css, svg

I made a responsive animation grid with SVG, but I dont know why my circles are stretched. When I resize window in some proportions, then circles looks nice.

There you can see - [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/rpnn3wxg/1/)

This is my SVG Code

```
<svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">

            <path id="firstLine" d="M 0 100 L 50 0, M 50 0 L 100 100 ,M 100 100 L 0 50 ,M 0 50 L 100 0,M 100 0 L 0 100" class="first-line" style="" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" fill="none" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />

            <path id="secondLine" d="M 100 100 L 0 0,    M 0 0 L 100 50,    M 100 50 L 0 100, M 0 100 L 25 0,    M 25 0 L 50 100,   M 50 100 L 75 0,   M 75 0 L 100 100" class="second-line" style="" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" fill="none" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />

            <path id="thirdLine" d="M 50 100 L 0 0,   M 0 0 L 25 100,   M 25 100 L 50 0,   M 50 0 L 75 100,   M 75 100 L 100 0,   M 100 0 L 50 100" class="third-line" style="" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" fill="none" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />

            <circle cx="" cy="" r="1%" fill="red" class="circle" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke">
                <animateMotion dur="60s" repeatCount="indefinite">
                    <mpath xlink:href="#firstLine"/>
                </animateMotion>
            </circle>

            <circle cx="" cy="" r="1%" fill="red" class="circle" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke">
                <animateMotion dur="60s" repeatCount="indefinite">
                    <mpath xlink:href="#secondLine"/>
                </animateMotion>
            </circle>

            <circle cx="" cy="" r="1%" fill="red" class="circle" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke">
                <animateMotion dur="60s" repeatCount="indefinite">
                    <mpath xlink:href="#thirdLine"/>
                </animateMotion>
            </circle>

            <circle cx="35" cy="20" r="1%" fill="red" class="circle" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke">
            </circle>


        </svg>
```

Comment: They are stretched because that's what you configured by setting preserveAspectRatio="none".

Comment: @RobertLongson yes, I know, but I need it responsive and full screen

Comment: You want two incompatible things. You'll need to pick one, won't you?

Comment: and how I can pick both? because I need them both, for my animations

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you dont need it now but I could do it giving the viewbox the desired ratio:
i.e: 0 0 100 100 for an square ratio
     0 0 25 100 for an vertical ratio
     0 0 100 25 for a horizontal ratio.

Then give to the svg tag a width and height of 100% and put the svg tag inside a div, this way I can keep the ratio of the circles, lines, other draws without stretching when the user resizes the window.